# Jupyter Notebook: Access to the file was denied

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, permissions

I'm trying to run a Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu 21.10. I've installed python, jupyter notebook, and all the various prerequisites. I added `export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin` to my `bashrc` so that the command `jupyter notebook` would be operational from the terminal.

When I call `jupyter notebook` from the terminal, I get the following error message from my browser:

```
Access to the file was denied.

The file at /home/username/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-260094-open.html is not readable.

    It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.
```

I'm using the latest version of FireFox.

I've read a number of guides on this and it seems to be a permissions error, but none of the guides that I've used have resolved the issue. Using `sudo` does not help, in fact it causes `Exception: Jupyter command "jupyter-notebook" not found.` to be thrown.

That being said, I am still able to access the notebook server. If I go to the terminal and instead click on the `localhost:8888` or IP address of the notebook server then it takes me to the notebook and everything runs without issue.

I would like to solve this so that when I run `jupyter notebook` I'm taken to the server and don't need to go back to the terminal window and click the IP address. It's inconvenient and can slow me down if I'm running multiple notebooks at once.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Chromium Version 96.0.4664.110

This was the solution in my case:

Create the configuration file with this command:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Edit the configuration file `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` and set:

```py
c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False
```

Make sure that this configuration parameter starts at the beginning of the line. If you leave one space at the beginning of the line, you will get the message that access to the file was denied.

**Otherwise** you can clean and reinstall JupyterLab

```
jupyter lab clean --all
pip3 install jupyterlab --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Generating and editing the config file as you suggested worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: also, make sure that `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False` is uncommented (remove the # at the start of the line, if there is any)

Comment: I can't edit configuration file: Permission denied.

Comment: did you generate the config file first ? i also specified in my answer that you shouldn't have a space at the beginning of the line otherwise you will get that denied access. If you can go through this you can try to make a clean reinstall.

Comment: It works with jupter-lab also, with minor changes: jupyter-lab --generate-config, and change c.ServerApp.use_redirect_file = False

Answer (score 11):

If anyone is curious, the reason for the problem is that the `file://` URI scheme cannot access files in hidden directories directly under the home directory (`~/.local` in your case).

You can recreate the problem with:
`mkdir ~/.test && echo "abc" > ~/.test/file.html && xdg-open ~/.test/file.html`

I couldn't find any reference for this behaviour in [RFC8089](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8089), and I also don't understand how the Jupyter authors missed this issue.

As LSeu suggested, the way to bypass the local redirection file, is to run:
`echo "c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

Another solution is to run `jupyter notebook --no-browser` and (Ctrl)-click the link in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

For those running Firefox installed with snap:

I think this issue has more to do with firefox installed with Snap, which somewhere along the way disallows Firefox access to hidden directories inside the /home/user folder in its sandboxed environment.

Another solution not mentioned in this thread (if you don't want to use another browser install) is to set the `JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR` env variable to a non-hidden directory in the `/home/user` folder:

```
# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
# append env variable to persistent user env file.  requires relogging in
echo JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/user/jupyter_runtime >> ~/.pam_environment
reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, try going directly to the other suggested URLs:  `http://localhost:8888/lab?token=<your-access-token>` or  `http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=<your-access-token>` (which is what setting the `...use_redirect_file = False` does)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked. I even reinstall conda (and looked at many other options). Thanks for this!