# Just updated Ubuntu to 22.04, now I can't open Jupyter Notebook

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, updates

When I try to launch Jupyter Notebook, the browser launches and I get the following error:

```
Access to the file was denied

The file at /home/benjamin/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-11758-open.html is not readable.

It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.
```

I tried running

```
jupyter lab clean --all
pip3 install jupyterlab --force-reinstall
```

as per the suggestion from here: [Jupyter Notebook: Access to the file was denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753768/jupyter-notebook-access-to-the-file-was-denied). The commands ran, but I still get the Access to the file was denied error. Also, on the reinstall command it spits this out:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqt5<5.13, which is not installed.
spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13, which is not installed.
conda-repo-cli 1.0.4 requires pathlib, which is not installed.
anaconda-project 0.9.1 requires ruamel-yaml, which is not installed.
spyder 4.2.5 requires jedi==0.17.2, but you have jedi 0.18.1 which is incompatible.
spyder 4.2.5 requires parso==0.7.0, but you have parso 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
sphinx 4.0.1 requires Jinja2<3.0,>=2.3, but you have jinja2 3.1.1 which is incompatible.
sphinx 4.0.1 requires MarkupSafe<2.0, but you have markupsafe 2.1.1 which is incompatible.
python-language-server 0.36.2 requires jedi<0.18.0,>=0.17.2, but you have jedi 0.18.1 which is incompatible.
fermipy 1.0.1+5.g5a57 requires astropy<4, but you have astropy 4.2.1 which is incompatible.
```

which may or may not be part of the problem.

Cross posted here: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/after-updating-to-ubuntu-22-04-i-am-no-longer-able-to-access-jupyter-notebook/13991

here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404330/after-updating-to-ubuntu-22-04-i-am-no-longer-able-to-access-jupyter-notebook

and on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/uaipzo/i_just_updated_my_machine_to_ubuntu_2204_now_i/

Comment: Please note when you cross-post the same question at multiple sites. [Duplicate post at the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/after-updating-to-ubuntu-22-04-i-am-no-longer-able-to-access-jupyter-notebook/13991?u=fomightez).

Comment: @Wayne Good point, I added the links to the cross posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: I am able to access the notebook now by using the URL printed to the console. (just copy and paste it into the Firefox browser)

I would still like to figure out how to get it to open with just the 'jupyter notebook" command the way it used to work before the update, but for now this is a useful workaround.

Comment: Adding on to this -  this isn't an issue with the Brave browser as changing the default opens Jupyter flawlessly. Gives me an intuition that Chrome would work fine (haven't tested it though)

Comment: Update2: If you are specifically looking to open on Firefox - then note that the snap version only has the problem. If you install the actual firefox from the website, it works as intended. Link : https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 2):

did you try setting

```
c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False
```

In the jupyter_notebook_configuration.py file?

If you tried, did you remove the '#' at the start of the line?

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04 and this fixed it.

Comment: Still no luck, after I modify that file, should I reinstall jupyter or should it just work? I get the same "access denied" error after making the changes you suggested...

Comment: I just updated to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, Codename: jammy. I had the same issue as posted in the question above. The answer by @Clopen solved my problem, after I ran `jupyter notebook --generate-config` in the terminal.

Comment: Do I have to reboot?  I tried all that and still nothing work

Answer (score 1):

I first created the file with :
jupyter notebook --generate-config
then I uncommented and change the line  c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file as you said

and now it works !

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue using Firefox from snap on Ubuntu 22.04.
I noticed that setting `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False` in generated `jupyter_notebook_config.py` works when launching `jupyter notebook`, but fails for `jupyter-lab` (error you pasted). I found that doing something similar to fix the problem for `jupyter-lab`:

```
jupyter server --generate-config
```

Then edit the generated `./jupyter/jupyter_server_config.py` and set `c.ServerApp.use_redirect_file = False`. Now running `jupter-lab` works in snap firefox too. Maybe you can try this way and just run via `jupyter-lab` if it works for you too.

Btw. none of this is needed if you just use Chrome, somehow the problem only occurs for firefox from snap on Ubuntu 22.04.
Otherwise you could check out `jupyter notebook --debug` and/or reinstalling JupyterLab.

Answer (score 0):

I use epiphany web browser instead of Firefox as a default web browser and everythings work fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found is that the launcher is not using a path to Jupyter Notebook that works.  From terminal I get:

```
$ whereis jupyter-notebook
jupyter-notebook: /home/brombo/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook /home/brombo/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

The command `/home/brombo/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook` will start notebook but `/home/brombo/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook` will not. If you use the first in the exec line of `.local/share/applications/jupyter-notebook.desktop` everything works -

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Jupyter Notebook
Comment=Run Jupyter Notebook
Exec=/home/brombo/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook %f
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=notebook
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=application/x-ipynb+json;
Categories=Development;Education;
Keywords=python;
```